# How to set timer of 5 min to do certain operation in app and if timeouts, raise another event to do other task

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, timer

I am developing airlines reservation app. Here, user selects flight and logs in. After login 5 min time is to be provided to him to complete his reservation, payment and confirm ticket. If his task is not completed within 5 min time, his reservation is to be cancelled. For cancelling, I need some event to be triggered. This event should not be triggered if user operation is completed within 5 min.

What is the best practices to do this in MVC 5 and C#?

I have found c# timer event method to accomplish the task but I am still not sure if I should use this or not. Is there better solution available? Also, not sure on how do I cancel reservation after time interval exceeds 5 min?

(Updated)
I found the solution and it worked exactly the way I wanted.
In case if someone might need the solution in future. I am positing in here.

```
private static void OnTimedEvent(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
    //do something
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Session["Timer"] == null)
    {
        Session["Timer"] = new System.Timers.Timer();
    }

    ((System.Timers.Timer)Session["Timer"]).Interval = 5000;
    ((System.Timers.Timer)Session["Timer"]).Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
    ((System.Timers.Timer)Session["Timer"]).AutoReset = true;
    ((System.Timers.Timer)Session["Timer"]).Enabled = true; 
}

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((System.Timers.Timer)Session["Timer"]).Enabled = false;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need cancellation to be an active event that is triggered by a timer? There is also the option to passively cancel reservations by comparing their creation time with current time. All incomplete reservations with interval longer that 5 min could be considered cancelled, and removed from the system using a automated daily maintenance job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CancellationTokenSource, where you can set a time out with method CancelAfter(). When time is up a OperationCanceledException will be thrown and you raise your event.